# Sequelize (Sqlite) does not recognize the association between the User and Collection Models in Discord bot

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord.js, sequelize.js

When a new user account is created, my discord bot is supposed to create a balance of coins and a collection that stores characters the user purchases with their coins. So the logic is each User has a Collection of Characters, their own copies of the same MasterCharacter (My Pikachu is level 10, yours is level 2).

All my console logs say that the two tables are associated, and I see them in DB Browser, but I keep getting this error.

```
Error in execute: EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Collection is not associated to User!
    at Function._getIncludedAssociation (C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:565:13)
    at Function._validateIncludedElement (C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:502:53)
    at C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:421:37    
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function._validateIncludedElements (C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:417:39)
    at Function.findAll (C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1124:12)
    at async Function.findOne (C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1240:12)
    at async Function.findOrCreate (C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1411:21)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\commands\Account\CreateAccount.js:20:31)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\headm\code\wicked-after-death-bot\events\InteractionCreate.js:43:7)
```

Here is where I initialize the tables:

dbInit.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('./Utils/sequelize');

const User = require('./Models/User.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
const Shop = require('./Models/Shop.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
const Collection = require('./Models/Collection.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
const Enemy = require('./Models/Enemy.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
const Character = require('./Models/Character.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
const MasterCharacter = require('./Models/MasterCharacter.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);

// Model connections
User.hasOne(Collection, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'collection' });
Collection.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'user' });


Collection.hasMany(Character, { foreignKey: 'collection_id', as: 'characters' });
Character.belongsTo(Collection, { foreignKey: 'collection_id' });

Character.belongsTo(MasterCharacter, { foreignKey: 'master_character_id', as: 'masterCharacter' });
MasterCharacter.hasMany(Character, { foreignKey: 'master_character_id', as: 'instances' });

const shopData = require('./db/dbShop');
const characterData = require('./db/dbCharacters');
const enemyData = require('./db/dbEnemies');

// Authenticates connection to the database.
sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(console.error);

// Sync changes and populate database
sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(async () => {
    const shopPromises = shopData.map(item => Shop.upsert(item));
    const characterPromises = characterData.map(async item => {
      try {
        await Collection.findCreateFind({
          where: { collection_id: item.character_id },
          defaults: item,
          onDuplicate: ['collection_id'],
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error syncing Collection:', error);
      }
    });
    const enemyPromises = enemyData.map(item => Enemy.upsert(item));
    console.log("User Associations:", Object.keys(User.associations));
console.log("Collection Associations:", Object.keys(Collection.associations));
    return Promise.all([...shopPromises, ...characterPromises, ...enemyPromises]);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('All databases synced');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error syncing databases:', error);
  });

async function fetchUserWithCollections(userId) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: { user_id: userId },
      include: [{
        model: Collection,
        as: 'collections'
      }],
    });
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
}


module.exports = { User, Shop, Collection, Enemy, fetchUserWithCollections };
```

User.js Model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    balance: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  });

  return User;
};
```

Collection.js Model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Collection = sequelize.define('Collection', {
      collection_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'user_id'
        }
      },
      // ... any other attributes specific to the collection itself
    }, {
      timestamps: false,
    });
  
    return Collection;
  };
```

Lastly, here is the command file for CreateAccount.js:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js')
const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../../Utils/sequelize')
const User = require('../../Models/User')(sequelize, DataTypes)
const Collection = require('../../Models/Collection')(sequelize, DataTypes)
const CharacterList = require('../../db/dbCharacters')

const specificCharacterIds = [0, 1, 2]

module.exports = {
  cooldown: 5,
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('create')
    .setDescription('Create your economy account'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const userId = interaction.user.id
    const t = await sequelize.transaction() // Initialize transaction

    try {
      const [user, created] = await User.findOrCreate({
        where: { user_id: userId },
        defaults: {
          balance: 730,
        },
        include: [{ model: Collection, as: 'collection' }], // Explicitly specify the foreignKey
        transaction: t,
      });

      // Function to calculate XP needed for next level
      const calculateXpNeeded = (level) => {
        if (level >= 1 && level <= 6) return 1000 * (level + 1)
        if (level >= 7 && level <= 8) return 6000 + (level + 1 - 6) * 2000
        if (level >= 9 && level <= 10) return 21000 + (level + 1 - 8) * 2000
        // more levels here
        return 1000 + (level - 1) * 1000
      }

      if (created) {
        await Promise.all(
          specificCharacterIds.map((id) => {
            const character = CharacterList.find((c) => c.character_id === id)
            return Collection.create(
              {
                collection_id: id,
                user_id: userId,
              },
              { transaction: t }
            )
          })
        )

        await t.commit() // Commit transaction

        return interaction.reply(
          `Your economy account has been created. You have 730 credits in your balance.`
        )
      } else {
        await t.rollback() // Rollback transaction
        return interaction.reply(
          `You already have an account. You currently have ${user.balance} coins in your account.`
        )
      }
    } catch (error) {
      await t.rollback() // Rollback transaction in case of error
      console.error('Error in execute:', error)
      return interaction.reply(
        'Something went wrong while creating your account.'
      )
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should use already initialized models instead of importing new ones once again in the `CreateAccount.js`:

```js
const { User, Collection } = require('../../db/dbInit')
...
```